# Firebase Function With Converter Wipes Document Reference on Set()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a scheduled function that resets an integer value back to zero in my firestore. The problem that I'm running into is that, while the merge-set succeeds (for the specified properties), it somehow resets my `Organization` document reference to null.

So far I've tried the following

- Not using a converter along with the `Update()` function (instead of `Set()`). While this works, it is untyped, and I have to get rid of the converter which encapsulates the moment() to Date conversion.
- Using `Set()` and simply pass the entire object.

```js
  user.reference?.withConverter(userConverter).set(user)
```

This is also working but it overrides the entire user object and can lead to concurrency issues in case a user also updates his object while the timed function is running.

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to use the converter class along with a merge `Set()`.

The `User` interface looks like this

```js
export interface User extends Document {
  email?: string
  name?: string
  organization?: Organization | null
  numberOfForwards?: number
  lastForwardReset?: moment.Moment
}
```

with its converter like so

```js
export class UserConverter implements firestore.FirestoreDataConverter<User> {
  toFirestore(user: User): firestore.DocumentData {
    return {
      email: user.email,
      name: user.name,
      organization: user.organization ? user.organization.reference : null,
      number_of_forwards: user.numberOfForwards,
      last_forward_reset: user.lastForwardReset?.toDate()
    }
  }
  fromFirestore(snapshot: firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot): User {
    const data = snapshot.data()!

    return {
      reference: snapshot.ref,
      email: data.email,
      name: data.name,
      organization: data.organization ? { reference: data.organization } : null,
      numberOfForwards: data.number_of_forwards,
      lastForwardReset: moment(data.last_forward_reset.toDate())
    }
  }
}
```

```js
export const resetNumberOfForwards = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('every 15 minutes')
  .onRun(async () => {
const reset = (user: User) => {
  console.log(`Resetting ${user.email} from [${user.numberOfForwards}] to [0]`)
  // Claim user reference
  user.reference
    ?.withConverter(userConverter)
    .set({ numberOfForwards: 0, lastForwardReset: Moment() }, { merge: true })
}
```

for the partial set to work, I've included the following snippet on top of my file

```js
firebase.firestore().settings({
  ignoreUndefinedProperties: true
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two issues going on here. For a partial [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) you should use  the **merge option** or else it will overwrite the document.

```
ref.set(data, {merge: true})
```

In addition, in your toFirestore method, either set the `organization` field as `undefined` and let the `ignoreUndefinedProperties: true` setting remove it, or don't include it at all if organization was not given. Something like this

```
toFirestore((numberOfForwards, lastForwardReset, ...user): User): firestore.DocumentData {
  if (user.organization) {
    user.organization = user.organization.reference;
  }
  return {
    ...user,
    number_of_forwards: numberOfForwards,
    last_forward_reset: lastForwardReset?.toDate()
  }
}
```

I took out the `numberOfForwards` and `lastForwardReset` fields from the user object here and use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy over the remaining fields to the return value, but you could also save a temporary object, modify it, and return that.

> PS: I know this is old, but it came up in my search so thought I might add an answer still.